# Docker: where is the newly created files under / stored?

Tags: docker

I was running a docker container process with:

```
host$ docker run -it <image> /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
```

Then inside of the container I created a file /a.txt:

```
container$ echo "abc" > /a.txt
container$ cat a.txt
abc
```

I noticed the filesystem type for / is none:

```
container$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            355G   19G  318G   6% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
...
```

The inspect command shows the volumes is null.

```
host$ docker inspect <image>
...
"Volumes": null,
...
```

After I exited the container process and restarted, the file disappeared. I wanted to understand:
1) what the root filesystem of the container process actually is;
2) how can I persist the newly created file?

Comment: you need to `docker commit` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** After I exited the container process and restarted, the file disappeared.

**A:** Data in a docker container is not persisted. That is you lost everything when that container gets restarted.

**Q:** What the root filesystem of the container process actually is? 
**A:** Don't really understand this question but I assume you are asking about where is the `root` user's home directory? If it is, then root's home is at `/root`.

**Q:** How can I persist the newly created file? 
**A:** If you are intending to keep the changes even after you restart the container then you will need to use docker's `data volume`.

See:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Essentially when you start the container, you can pass in the `-v` option to tell the container that you would like to map the directory from the host's file system to the container's directory.

That is by doing the example command below,
`$ docker run -d -P --name web -v $(pwd):/root`

You will you would like to map your current working directory to the container's `/root` directory. So everything gets written to the container's `/root/` area gets reflected to your host's file system and it is persisted.

Comment: @Dagang not sure why the downvote as well... But do let me know whether this helps.

Comment: For the "What the root filesystem of the container process actually is", I mean when I ran "df -h", it showed the type of the / filesystem is none. So, is it a in-memory filesystem? or a tmp filesystem mapped somewhere to the host filesystem.

Comment: @Dagang - I see. To be honest I'm not sure either, I tried to do some research just now but I didn't get anywhere... Based on its behaviour and docker's documentation where they say data belonging to a container are not persisted, I would say it is an in-memory file system.